# why mysql give me syntax error when build on cascade table

Tags: mysql, sql

**#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (`entry_id`) REFERENCES `entry`(`entry_id`) ON DELETE CAS' at line 10**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `comment` (
  `comment_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `entry_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `comment_name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `comment_email` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `comment_body` text NOT NULL,
  `comment_state` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `comment_created` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    PRIMARY KEY (`comment_id`)
   CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (`entry_id`) REFERENCES `entry`(`entry_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE 
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=34 ;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot a comma after the PRIMARY KEY line.

Comment: thanks mr.bill ..one another question..why i cant insert to comment table directly..how to do it..thanks again

Comment: #1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`pro`.`comment`, CONSTRAINT `comment_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`entry_id`) REFERENCES `entry` (`entry_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE)

Comment: You have to create the row in the `entry` table first, so that the foreign key constraint will be met.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, You need to add a comma (`,`)

```
   PRIMARY KEY (`comment_id`),
```

Comment: Same as the answer from 4 minutes before?

Comment: @Barmar - Yes when I started posting my answer I did not see his show up -- crossed in the editing / wires.